# Selenium: scroll down, then no more links than previous state

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code, I know it scroll down very well in non headless mode.

```
lenght = 0
last = 0
full_items_list_temp = []

# scroll down code. Number of links is 25
while True:
    html = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
    html.send_keys(Keys.END)
    full_items_list_temp = self.driver.find_elements(
        By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href, "/item/")]')
    length = len(full_items_list_temp)
    if length == last:
        break
    else:
        last = length

sleep(1)

# Fetch all links, should be > 100
full_items_list = self.driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href, "/item/")]')

for item in full_items_list:
    try:
        link = item.get_attribute('href')
        print(link)
    except:
        pass
```

But the number of links is not updated. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

@Anthony found a typo in my code, but that was not the issue.

The issue was the lack of `sleep()`, now it works as expected:

```
length = 0
last = 0
full_items_list_temp = []
while True:
    sleep(2)                                                   # <- mandatory here
    html = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
    html.send_keys(Keys.END)
    full_items_list_temp = self.driver.find_elements(
        By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href, "/item/")]')
    length = len(full_items_list_temp)
    if length == last:
        print("REACHED END OF PAGE")
        break
    else:
        last = length
```